# Sidebar Gadget not Running ActiveX Control

Tags: javascript, activex, windows-desktop-gadgets

I built a gadget that shows an on-call rotation for a team, and I am trying to integrate their communicator presence into that shedule. I am using the [GetStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802706.aspx/) method from the [NameCtrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms455335.aspx) object to get user presence. It works fine in IE when I run it. The problem I am having is that the gadget has a runtime error whenever it hits the ActiveX object declaration. I know this because I commented it out and it runs fine. Any suggestions?

```
var communicatorPresence = getCommunicatorPresence(userName);


function getCommunicatorPresence(userName){
 var obj = new ActiveXObject("Name.NameCtrl.1")
 var presence = obj.GetStatus(userName,"")
 return presence;
}
```

I debugged the gadget in Visual Studio and put a breakpoint there, and the error was "Automation Server can't create object"

Comment: Have you tested on any other machines?  Usually "Automation Server can't create object" means that either the control isn't properly registered or the current user/application isn't allowed to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the machines UAC settings it might be that gadget does not have read/write access the registry.